# Python FTPlib is creating files with unix clrf instead of windows cldf

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm on a Windows PC and I'm trying to download files from an FTP. The files download fine, but the only issue when I open them up in Notepad is that it's displayed with a Unix (LF). I've tried a couple of different fixes to be able to get it to be a Windows (CRLF), but nothing is working. The file is a UTF-16-LE encoded file.

Here are two sources I looked at two fix this, but nothing:

[How to correctly download files using ftplib so line breaks are added for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224091/how-to-correctly-download-files-using-ftplib-so-line-breaks-are-added-for-window)

https://effbot.org/librarybook/ftplib.htm

My code is currently as follows:

```
def downloadFiles(self, files, localFolder):

    with FTP(host=self.host, user=self.username, passwd=self.password) as ftp:
        ftp.cwd(self.root)
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(localFolder, file.fileName), 'w', newline=None) as f:
                ftp.retrlines(f'RETR {file.fileName}', lambda line, file=f: file.write(line+'\n'))
```

I've tried the **line+'\r\n**, but it just adds an extra line space instead.

Anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the issue in the future with a utf-16 file you just need to set the ftp encoding to utf-16. I was looking for an encoding option at the file level, but apparently you need to set it at the connection level.

```
    with FTP(host=self.host, user=self.username, passwd=self.password) as ftp:
        ftp.encoding = 'utf-16'
        ftp.cwd(self.root)
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(localFolder, file.fileName), 'w', encoding='utf-16') as f:
                ftp.retrlines(f'RETR {file.fileName}', lambda line: f.write(line + '\n'))
```

Comment: UTF-16 should have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I don't know enough to argue, but when I changed the encoding for the connection it fixed the issue I had.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple command line utility [unix2dos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos).

You can use use `unix2dos` utility on the files after ftp.

Also if you are text editing the file, use `Notepad++` .
With `Notepad++` you can manage the file's newline format and its encoding as well.

[image]